# Is there any way to prevent a RecyclerView from Detaching views?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to prevent a RecyclerView from detaching views? I'm stuck in a situation where I need live offscreen views, and when I scroll out of the item's view in a RecyclerView, onViewDetachedFromWindow is called.

The use case is a multi-stream video player using an SDK that unfortunately has Thread.Sleeps and requires using the main thread so it doesn't crash. I have no access to the internals of this SDK, so I cannot change this behaviour.

The SDK creates each of it's widgets inherited from a FrameLayout, and if I don't close the underlying media source, I get a JNI exception complaining about a surface that disappeared. So, for this reason, I call SDK.close() in onViewDetachedFromWindow and SDK.open() in onViewAttachedToWindow.

The problem here is that when I fling through feeds, there is a VERY choppy scroll behaviour due to the main thread work in opening/closing the SDK streams.

Previously, I had a ViewPager with a large offscreen limit and this works great after the initial loading of all the feeds (perfectly seamless scrolling). However, now I have to provide different viewing patterns (one screen at a time, 2x2 grids, etc) which are a great use case for the LayoutManagers and are annoying to create as ViewPagers (also there are various types of touch interactions that I'm not mentioning - hard to manage in a ViewPager).

I've also tried delaying the SDK open and close calls until scrolling has completed - but that leads to strange behaviours sporadically.

On the RecyclerView side, neither setItemViewCacheSize nor isRecycleable doesn't seem to make a difference regarding detaching views. I've also tried overriding getExtraLayoutSpace in the LayoutManager and it didn't seem to solve the choppy scrolling either.

Finally, my current workaround is just to use the PagerSnapHelper to only allow a 'scroll-by-one' functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Setting the View Holder's [isRecyclable property to false](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#setIsRecyclable(boolean)) doesn't do the trick?

Comment: Not as far as I can see, that has to do more with recycling/collection - rather than view attaching/detaching

Answer (score 0):

To prevent that from happening, you need to override these methods in the adapter and then leave them empty:

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {}

override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {}
```

And then you should add the `setRecyclerListener` and then set the recyclable property to false like this:

```
binding.recyclerView.setRecyclerListener {
    it.setIsRecyclable(false)
}
```